# Search in drop-down list Works on all Android devices except some devices such as Note10+

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

TypeAheadFormField The code worked in most devices and Android to In most versions of note10+, the user searches, then the search results appear, and when chosen, the drop-down list is canceled, and the item is not selected

```
 Expanded(
          child: TypeAheadFormField<ProductModel>(textFieldConfiguration: TextFieldConfiguration(
                    focusNode: _focusScopeNode,
                    textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: "أسم الصنف",
                    hintTextDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                //  labelText: "أسم الصنف",
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20), // زيادة المساحة بين حدود الحقل والنص
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15.0))),
                     ),
                    controller: TextEditingController(text: SelectedProduct?.productAsStringByName()), // تعيين المنتج المختار كقيمة افتراضية للـ TextField
                  ),
                  suggestionsCallback: (String pattern) async {
                    return await getProductDataDropdown(pattern, listOfProducts);
                  },
                  itemBuilder: (context, ProductModel suggestion) {
                    return ListTile(title: Text(suggestion.productName,
                        textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                      ),
                      subtitle: Text('${money.format(suggestion.productPrice)}RY', //textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                        style: TextStyle(color: color),),);},
                      onSuggestionSelected: (ProductModel suggestion) {
                      setState(() {SelectedProduct = suggestion;
                      priceController = TextEditingController(text: SelectedProduct?.productPrice.toString());
                      print(SelectedProduct?.productPrice.toString());
                      isProductSelected = true; // تعيين حالة المنتج المختار إلى true عند اختيار المنتج
                    });
                    _focusScopeNode.unfocus();
                  },
                ),
              ),
```

TypeAheadFormField The code worked in most devices and Android to In most versions of note10+, the user searches, then the search results appear, and when choosing, the drop-down menu is canceled, and the item is not chosen, is the defect from the sdk version or from compileSdkVersion 33
ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion